# Cargar archivo CSV en MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola esperando que me puedan ayudar.

Estoy intentando cargar un archivo csv el cual el _pt_part_ debo separarlo en 3 partes

> EJ. carácter completo es 12345678910250L
>
> Tengo que separarlo en 3 campos:
>
> |123456789| 102 | 50L |

la carga ya la puedo realizar pero no he podido separar los caracteres

```
<?php
    # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cargamasiva");
    if(!$con){
        die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $productos = fopen ("/var/www/html/xxxxxx/p/pt_mstr.csv", "r" );//leo el archivo que contiene los datos del producto
        //Leo linea por linea del archivo hasta un maximo de 1000 caracteres por linea leida usando coma(,) como delimitador
        while (($datos = fgetcsv($productos,10000,";")) !== FALSE )
        {
            $linea[]=array('pt_part'=>$datos[0],'pt_draw'=>$datos[1],'pt_promo'=>$datos[2],'pt_desc1'=>$datos[3],'pt_rev'=>$datos[4]);//Arreglo Bidimensional para guardar los datos de cada linea leida del archivo
         /*$linea[]=array('pt_proveedor'=>$datos[0],'pt_pi'=>$datos[1],'pt_part'=>$datos[2],'pt_draw'=>$datos[3],'pt_promo'=>$datos[4],'pt_desc1'=>$datos[5],'pt_rev'=>$datos[6]);//Arreglo Bidimensional para guardar los datos de cada linea leida del archivo*/
        }
    fclose ($productos);//Cierra el archivo

    $ingresado=0;//Variable que almacenara los insert exitosos
    $error=0;//Variable que almacenara los errores en almacenamiento
    $duplicado=0;//Variable que almacenara los registros duplicados
    $actualizado=0;//Variable que almacenara los registros duplicados


    foreach($linea as $indice=>$value) //Iteracion el array para extraer cada uno de los valores almacenados en cada items
    {   
        //$pt_proveedor=$value["pt_proveedor"];// proveedor
        //$pt_pi=$value["pt_pi"]; //pi = producto importado
        $pt_part=$value["pt_part"];//pt_part = articulo
        $pt_draw=$value["pt_draw"];//pt_draw = familia
        $pt_promo=$value["pt_promo"];//pt_promo = temporada de venta
        $pt_desc1=$value["pt_desc1"];//pt_desc1 = descripcion
        $pt_rev=$value["pt_rev"];//pt_rev = Marca

        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from productos where pt_part='$pt_part'");//Consulta a la tabla productos
        $num=mysqli_num_rows($sql);//Cuenta el numero de registros devueltos por la consulta
        if ($num==0)//Si es == 0 inserto
            {
if ($insert=mysqli_query($con,"insert into productos (pt_part, pt_draw, pt_promo, pt_desc1, pt_rev) values('$pt_part','$pt_draw','$pt_promo','$pt_desc1','$pt_rev')"))

            /*if ($insert=mysqli_query($con,"insert into productos (pt_proveedor, pt_pi, pt_part, pt_draw, pt_promo, pt_desc1, pt_rev) values('$pt_proveedor','$pt_pi','$pt_part','$pt_draw','$pt_promo','$pt_desc1','$pt_rev')"))*/
                $ingresado+=1;

            }
        else 
            {
                if ($update=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE productos SET pt_draw='$pt_draw', pt_promo='$pt_promo', pt_desc1='$pt_desc1', pt_rev='$pt_rev' WHERE pt_part='$pt_part'"))

                /*if ($update=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE productos SET pt_proveedor='$pt_proveedor', pt_pi='$pt_pi', pt_draw='$pt_draw', pt_promo='$pt_promo', pt_desc1='$pt_desc1', pt_rev='$pt_rev' WHERE pt_part='$pt_part'"))*/
                $actualizado+=1;


            }

    }
```

Comment: Como csv significa _comma separated values_ puedes usar [php:explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para separar las lineas, aun no veo comas en tu ejemplo de los datos que cargas. como es eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para separarlo puedes usar la función `substr($string, $start, $length)`. Sería algo así:

```
$caracter_completo = 12345678910250L;
$parte1 = substr($caracter_completo, 0, 9);//empieza desde el cero, 9 caracteres de longitud
$parte2 = substr($caracter_completo, 9, 3);
$parte3 = substr($caracter_completo, 12, 3);
```

Lo que hace es pasar el código completo a separar, el segundo parámetro es el caracter donde empieza y el tercer parámetro es la cantidad de caracteres que va a incluir.

Comment: Andres. me funciona perfectamente pero cuando llamo al $pt_part me guarda ese valor?

Comment: Lo que hace es que separa el código en 3 partes, dependiendo de la estructura de tu base de datos debes armar el query para pasar estos tres valores de acuerdo a lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias estimado. me sirvio bastante

Answer (score 0):

Si es una carga ocasional puedes probar con esta web:
[http://file2sql.com](http://file2sql.com?utm_source=es.stackoverflow&utm_medium=reply&utm_campaign=csv_mysql)

A partir de un fichero csv detecta tipos de datos y retorna un script mysql que crea y rellena la tabla.